# React router Link only renders the route specified in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have this react app where the structure is
EnglishRoute -> Mainpage -> Treatments -> TreatmentItem

In the EnglishRoute, I have:

```
<p>english route</p>
<Switch>
  <Route path=`en` exact>
    <MainPage />  
  </Route>
  <Route path=`en/quote`>
    <NewQuote />
  </Route>
  <Route path=`en/rendering`>
    <Regions />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

In my TreatmentItem.js I have:

```
  <li>
    <Link to=`en/rendering`>Rendering React</Link>
  </li>
</ul>

<Switch>
  <Route path=`en/rendering`>
    <Regions />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

I want to be able to render the component `<Regions>` from TreatmentItem.js but it does
not work. But when have the same `` <Route path=`en/rendering`> `` inside `EnglishRoute`, it
gets the same `<Regions />` component rendered and everything loads fine...

`` <Link to=`en/rendering`> `` correctly put the url.

I feel like I am forgetting something really silly, what can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

Inside the `Switch` component route path order and specificity matters. In this case you've added the `exact` prop to the `Route` rendering `MainPage` on path`"/en"`. When you click the link and navigate to `"/en/rendering"` the path no longer ***exactly*** matches `"/en"` and the `MainPage` component is unmounted.

This is why the `path="en/rendering"` route works when it's outside on it's own with the `Switch` but not when it's rendered by `MainPage`/../`TreatmentItem`.

## Solution

The route path order and specificity matters inside the `Switch`. If ordered correctly there is almost ***zero*** need to use the `exact` prop. Reorder the routes in the inverse order of path specificity, i.e. the ***more*** specific routes should be listed before the ***less*** specific routes. Remove the `exact` prop.

Example:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="en/quote" component={NewQuote} />
  <Route path="en" component={MainPage} />
</Switch>
```

Now when the path is `"/en/rendering"` it won't match `"/en/quote"` and route matching will continue down and be matched by `"/en"` and render the `MainPage` component. Since `MainPage` is rendering `TreatmentItem` and another `Switch` with a `Route` on `"/en/rendering"` this path is *also* matched and the `Regions` component is rendered.